# Enviar dato por GET a un HTML según consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones, else

Tengo 2 tablas separadas en mysql:

`id  |  codigo  |   respuesta1  |   respuesta 2   |    respuesta 3   |`

y

`id  |  codigo  |   respuesta4  |   respuesta 5   |    respuesta 6   |`

Necesito enviar el valor código por método get con la finalidad de saber si existe en algúna tabla:

```
<?php 
echo "<td>
     <form action='verificar.php?pin=".$row['codigo']."'method='POST'> 
         <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'></button>
     </form>
     </td>"; 
?>
```

Al recíbir dicho dato (codigo) **se debe saber si existe en Tabla 1 o Tabla 2**

Tengo planeado lo siguiente:

```
 verificar.php

$sql1 = "consulta a tabla1";
$sql2 = "consulta a tabla2";

$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];

if($codigo esta en $sql1){
//enviar codigo a HTML1
}else{
//enviar codigo a HTML2
}
```

Algún consejo?? Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, por favor edita y trata de explicart mejor

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias por la observación, espero haber sido más específica.

Comment: Si vas a mandar un dato por URL entonces el verbo a usar es GET, ya que este es también el que tienes en tu .php

Comment: Debo tener un archivo php que verifique si el dato envíado por get este en una tabla o en otra y de ahí mandarlo a un archivo html o a otro, dependiendo en cual de las dos tablas se encuentre.

Comment: Me parece una lógica extraña la que estás siguiendo, por varios motivos: 1) para saber si `codigo` está en alguna de las tablas tienes que lanzar **dos consultas** y verificar el estado de **ambas** 2) `codigo` podría estar **en las dos tablas**, ¿qué pasaría en ese caso? 3) parecen tablas **similares**, ¿por qué las tienes diferenciadas? ¿**no sería más fácil tener una sola tabla**? ¿qué justifica que sean dos tablas? teniendo una sola tabla te ahorras todo el embrollo en el que te estás metiendo, pues sería consultar a la tabla única donde están los datos...

Comment: @A.Cedano que en realidad Tabla A tiene 45 valores y Tabla B tiene 72.

Comment: @A.Cedano tanto como para un html elabora un gráfica en php y el otro elabora otra ,, por eso tienen ***que estar separados***

Comment: Ninguno de tus dos argumentos justifica que las tablas tengan que estar separadas. Si reflexionas, eso lo único que hace es complicarlo todo y ralentizarlo todo. Las bases de datos está capacitadas para guardar millones de filas, con contenido de todo tipo. Una BD puede guardar una biblioteca entera, los datos de todos los habitantes de un país o de millones de productos.